# How can I see where a Vim macro went wrong?

Tags: vim

Sometimes when running a Vim macro the results aren't exactly as expected. Is there a way to "debug" this?

For example, it I could slow down macro execution and see what the input was for each step it would be very easy to see the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I do is edit the macro, either by putting and then yanking the register in a scratch buffer, or directly on the command line (`:let @q = <C-r>=string(@q)<CR>`). Unless I see the error, this usually means cutting of the tail of the macro to see where it goes wrong.

You could alternatively try to intersperse `[N]gs` (i.e. sleep N seconds) commands, if that helps you.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that you could view macro registers. It's `:reg q` to view the `q` register, for anyone else who's wondering.